# Filtering specific float values based on a condition

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataFrame column price having a price feature having 10000+ values ranging from 0$ to 399.99$.

I'm trying to segregate value as per certain price band but getting incorrect values.

> Price(values) given are:

```
array([  0.  ,   4.99,   3.99,   6.99,   1.49,   2.99,   7.99,   5.99,
         3.49,   1.99,   9.99,   7.49,   0.99,   9.  ,   5.49,  10.  ,
        24.99,  11.99,  79.99,  16.99,  14.99,   1.  ,  29.99,  12.99,
       109.99, 154.99,   3.08,   2.59,   4.8 ,   1.96,  19.4 ,   3.9 ,
         4.59,  15.46,   3.04,   4.29,   2.6 ,   3.28,   4.6 ,  28.99,
         2.95,   2.9 ,   1.97, 200.  ,  89.99,   2.56,  30.99,   3.61,
       394.99,   1.26,   1.2 ,   1.04], dtype=float32)
```

Tried below code, but getting wrong Output despite having value > 28,

```
(data['Price'].any() > 28:
        print('Max')
# is returning False
```

> ```
> def Priceband():
>     if data['Price'].any() < 7:
>         print('Cheap')
>     if data['Price'].any() >= 7 & data['Price'].any() < 14:
>         print('Normal')
>     if data['Price'].any() >= 14 & data['Price'].any() < 21:
>         print('Slight Expensive')
>     if data['Price'].any() >= 21 & data['Price'].any() < 28:
>         print('Expensive')
>     if data['Price'].any() > 28:
>         print('Max')
> ```

Getting 'False' even for 'True' Conditions

Comment: I think this is not the correct use of the .any function. This function returns a boolean so it should only return True  in the first if (because True = 1 and False = 0).

Answer (score 1):

The use of `any` is not correct. Additionally, with the use of `elif` you don't do unneccessary `if`-checks:

```
if (data['Price'] < 7).any():
    print('Cheap')
elif (data['Price'] >= 7 and data['Price'] < 14).any():
    print('Normal')
elif (data['Price'] >= 14 and data['Price'] < 21).any():
    print('Slight Expensive')
elif (data['Price'] >= 21 and data['Price'] < 28).any():
    print('Expensive')
elif (data['Price'] > 28).any():
    print('Max')
```

However, consider using `pandas.cut`. In case one of the borders changes, you only have to adjust one hard-coded number instead of two. Plus readability increases.

```
bins = [0, 7, 14, 21, 28, 400]
labels = ['Cheap', 'Normal', 'Slight Expensive', 'Expensive', 'Max']
data['Price Band'] = pd.cut(data['Price'], bins=bins, labels=labels)
```

Answer (score 0):

[any](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) checks whether any value is `True`. Thus, you need to do the check before and then call `any`:

```py
if (data['Price'] < 7).any():
        print('Cheap')
```

Any numeric value that is above 0 will return true for a boolean check:

```py
pd.DataFrame({'Price': [0., 0.1, 0.5, 1.0, 2.0]}).astype('bool')
>>> Price
0   False
1   True
2   True
3   True
4   True
```